# Counting quantifiers - how

Tags: alloy

Let's say, I have to model a checkerboard and I want to say that at least 5 squares on the "A" vertical are empty. How do I do that in Alloy? Any other example with numbers different from 0 or 1 would be good. In other words, what do I do when "some" is not precise enough?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the cardinality operator (#) to make assertions about the number of tuples in a relation, e.g.,

```
#r >= 5
```

says that the relation `r` must have at least 5 tuples.

You can also use the cardinality operator with an arbitrary expression, e.g.,

```
#board.cells >= 5
```

or

```
#{c: Cell | c in board.cells and ...} >= 5
```